# Send large JSON string

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I'm trying to send large json string in my c# application to an asp.net page using querystring (POST method), but because the string is too long it give me this msg: Invalid uri: the uri link is too long.

Is there is another solution for my problem !?

```
if(allRecords.Count > 0)
    for (int j = 0; j < allRecords.Count; j++)
    {
        queryString += JsonConvert.SerializeObject(allRecords[j], Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
    }
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(queryString);

// Set up Request.
HttpWebRequest webReq = WebRequest.Create(onlineApp) as HttpWebRequest;
webReq.ContentType = "text/plain";
webReq.Method = "POST";
webReq.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
webReq.ContentLength = data.Length;

// Send Request.


Stream newStream = webReq.GetRequestStream();
newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
newStream.Close();

// get Response.
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webReq.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

string tt = reader.ReadToEnd();

reader.Close();
response.Close();
```

Comment: POST data is not part of the URI, so the error doesn't make much sense to me. What does the ASP.NET page do with the POST data? Could the error be there?

Comment: How about using the `WebClient` class and one of the [`WebClient.UploadData` overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdbbwh0a(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of the `WebRequest` class?

Comment: I might be missing it, but based only on the above, what is `querystring`? The variable name? The actual `query string` (of uri)? I see the former (which you seem to be POSTing)..but not the latter...

Comment: Svick..the error occure in c# page .. before i can send it !
and my querystring is too long .. i check it.
i need to send the json string to asp.net page !

Comment: I dont see where you are creating you URL.   Is the URL the onlineApp variable?  There would be no need to create a URL with a querystring if you are POSTing the data.  e.g. http://www.com?s=querystring.  If the API is expecting a POST, it will bring in the data you are writing to the request stream.

Comment: Also depending on the API the content type may need to be "application/json"

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem in your WebRequest , when you create new Webrequest , check you webrequest string.